# Google App Engine - Cloud Endpoints - Application name is not set

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I just started Google Cloud Endpoints.

When running android app, I have the following warning in logcat:

```
Tag: AbstractGoogleClient
Text: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
```

Where to set Application name? Is it in android or app engine/cloud endpoints?

Answer (score 6):

The Class `com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient` has a function

```
public Builder setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
      this.applicationName = applicationName;
      return this;
    }
```

When using [Gradle to generate your client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/setup) using `appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs`
You should be able to create an endpointbuilder for your endpoints:

```
private YourEndpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new YourEndpoint.Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
            new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
                }
            }
    );
```

then... to get rid of the warning:

```
endpointBuilder.setApplicationName("Some crazy App Name");
```