# Google App Engine Requires Application Name to be Set

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google Cloud Endpoints and have deployed the back-end globally. Now I am trying to run android application on Mobile. The documentation [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints) shows that while deploying the application, I need to edit  tag and enter my project id, which I have done.

However, running the application on mobile gives me the following error:

```
AbstractGoogleClient﹕ Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
```

There is another [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672184/google-app-engine-cloud-endpoints-application-name-is-not-set) question here but hasn't been answered appropriately. Please help!

Comment: Have you also tried the answer to that question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26746953/568169

Comment: Yes. endpointBuilder of class _Builder_ has no method setApplicationName

Answer (score 1):

I know its pretty late but this can be helpful to someone else.

You should add the application name when you try to build.

Refer this [Set Application Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650480/4183646)