# How to set the application name using the HTTP Client Library for Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-http-client

I am using the [HTTP Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/) to access the Google Custom Search API and perform a search.

```
 String key = "...";
 String cx = "...";
 String query = "...";
 // Set up the HTTP transport and JSON factory
 HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
 JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

 Customsearch customsearch = new Customsearch(httpTransport, jsonFactory,null);
 List<Result> resultList = null;
 try {
       Customsearch.Cse.List list = customsearch.cse().list(query);
       list.setKey(key);
       list.setCx(cx);      
       Search results = list.execute();
 }catch (Exception e) {
       LOG.debug("Exception: " + e);
 }
```

Although it works, I always get this warning:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient 
>   WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.

How can I set the application name using the HTTP Client Library for Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [Customsearch.Builder](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/customsearch/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/customsearch/Customsearch.Builder.html) instead of the Customsearch constructor. Example:

```
Customsearch customsearch = new Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).setApplicationName("your application name").build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Update your comment to `Customsearch customsearch = new Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).setApplicationName("your application name").build();` and I will accept it.